# Implementing unit-of-work for multiple storage types

Tags: c#, design-patterns, database, unit-of-work, windows-registry

I'm trying to implement the unit-of-work pattern for mutliple storage types like the windows registry, a database or the app.config but I cannot figure out how to do it. All examples I find use Entity Framework which already is a UoW so it doesn't help much. What I'd like to store is a simple `Setting` object.

From http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html I understand that

> A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work.

So I probably should start with a class that has two settable properties and one that tells me whether it's dirty and needs an update.

```
class Setting
{
    private string _value;

    public Setting(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        _value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            IsDirty = true;
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirty { get; private set; }
}
```

then I guess I need a base repository:

```
abstract class SettingRepository
{
    private readonly List<Setting> _settings = new List<Setting>();

    public abstract IEnumerable<Setting> Get(Setting setting);

    public void Add(IEnumerable<Setting> settings)
    {
        _settings.AddRange(settings);
    }

    public abstract int SaveChanges();
}
```

and a unit-of-work as `SettingContext`:

```
abstract class SettingContext
{
    protected SettingContext(SettingRepository settings)
    {
        Settings = settings;
    }

    public SettingRepository Settings { get; }
}
```

---

Now I'm not sure where I should put all the Update/Insert/SaveChanges logic? A database would for example support transaction whereas the windows registry not.

Do I need different repositories for each storage type or do I need different unit-of-work aka contexts for each of them? I'm really confused.

---

I don't know what exactly I should do next. Maybe I think to much Entity Framework and try to implement it in a too similar way like this:

```
using(var context = new SettingContext(new RegistryRepository()))
{
    context.Settings.Add(new Setting("Foo", "Bar")); // this should be created
    context.Settings.Add(otherSetting); // this should be updated
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You can write to registry in a transactional manner, using the Kernel Transaction Manager component. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986748(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: A note on patterns - don't try to use patterns because they are patterns. Try to find a solution to solve your problem based on your requirements. Patterns are a consequence of coding logic, not a buffet of building blocks you choose from.

Comment: @ThalesPereira I completely agree. I have never had the need for the UoW before but perhaps it is because I don't entirely understand it. The example with saving settings into various data stores seemed like an easy case to try it out. In my current implementation I use repositories with a common interface and I wanted to implement it the UoW way to see for myself whether I has any advantanges over my current solution. Unfortunatelly I seem to be not the only one who doesn't get it because so far no one could tell how in this example a _correct_ implemention should look like.

Comment: @ThalesPereira to estimate its real value I need to see it in action for myself. I don't take things for granted just because someone said this pattern is great so use it. I'll wait. Maybe there is someone who **really** knows how it works and not just pretends by using EF behind the scene that does the actual work and skips the most important parts of the actual implementation.

Comment: @t3chb0t The thing is - there is not such a thing of a _correct_ UoW, or any other pattern as far as coding goes. There is _code_ that _works somewhat similar to other programs_. Patterns are like "animal types" - there is not such a thing as a correct bird, but we can identify an animal as a bird because of a plenitude of shared traits. The same goes for any coding pattern.

Comment: @t3chb0t There are several ways of implementing something that works like an Unit of Work. What exactly it does and how it behaves depend heavily on your requirements, however. _Your requirements_ should come first. If they ask you do to XYZ, you do it, and then you step back and look at your code, and you think: "Oh, this looks like pattern ABC".

Comment: @t3chb0t So, really - what you will see in action is not the Unit of Work pattern, it's the code to solve the problem at hand. My Unit of Work code to solve my database needs may not solve your needs, but that doesn't mean my code is wrong. Really, forget patterns while you are coding. Use them later, to see what you _did_, but not to decide what you should _do_.

Comment: @t3chb0t (Also, take anything that comes from Martin Fowler - actually, from everyone, really - with a grain of salt - Fowler is a _great programmer_, but he is also human and sometimes he puts out some ideas that look great on a teaching book but don't survive contact with all types of business environments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine so far. The "Unit-of-Work" class should get the responsibility to keep track of the changes to your "settings entity" for one "transaction" (it could do this, for example, by keeping a list of commands or changed objects, if there would be more than one object involved), and the abstract repository should provide an abstraction for the CRUD operations (so there will be one concrete repository implementation for each type of storage, that is fine). The "Commit" operation of the "UoW" then just loops over the commands or changed objects and uses the CRUD operations of the injected repo to store the data/changes.

However, if all the data you have to manage is contained in just one settings object, and the update operation is just to write that object into the storage in one transaction, using a "Unit-of-Work" approach is probably overkill. UoW makes more sense if you need some kind of parentheses around a complex transaction, involving multiple objects. For your `Settings` object, a repo with methods like `SaveSettings` and `LoadSettings` is probably sufficient.

Comment: Ok, great ;-) I actaully have this now as different repositories without an UoW but as I've never implemented UoW yet I thought this example is super easy so if I get how it works with a single entity type then it should be much esier to add more later or such features as change tracking for which UoW seems to be the right choice.